# Python Turtle shows blank screen when running code

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've begun to experiment with turtle on Python 3.5, and I've encountered an odd error. My code is:

```
 import turtle                    
 wn = turtle.Screen()             
 bob = turtle.Turtle()      
 bob.forward(150)               
 bob.left(90)               
 bob.forward(75)
```

Oddly enough, when I first ran this, it worked perfectly, but now every time it shows a blank turtle screen. When I run this line-by-line, I get to this error message from line 3:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "pyshell#2", line 1, in 
>       bob = turtle.Turtle()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 3816, in **init**
>       visible=visible)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 2557, in **init**
>       self._update()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
>       self._update_data()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
>       self.screen._incrementudc()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
>
> ```
> raise Terminator
> ```
>
> turtle.Terminator

If I try and call bob after this, the shell tells me it is not defined... Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my guess:  I believe the error you're triggering is this:

```
   if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
        TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
        raise Terminator
```

I'm assuming you're not running a file but instead pasting commands into an interpreter -- which is fine.  But if you close the turtle graphics window, it won't reopen for you.  You can try restarting your interpreter anew, or you might try doing a `turtle.bye()` and then running your commands again -- sometimes it works to reopen the window, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using macOS, try installing python-tk by using this command:

```
  brew install python-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue with Turtle graphics and PythonWin. On second run the screen is displayed but script hangs when new turtle class is instanced. 
But when I run it with IDLE, the script can be ran over and over.